How to build cylinders similar to this, but in reverse?
How to build cylinder in tikz like shown in this example
The example above builds a set of ever-larger cylinders on top of each other with texts on the side, starting at the bottom.
The example output and code is replicated here. The source is the link above.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{myellow}{RGB}{228,212,0}
\definecolor{mgreen}{RGB}{5,104,57}

\newcommand\funnel[3]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\mwid{(2+\xi*.7)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\marc{\mwid-.4}
    \begin{scope}[%
        shift={(0,#1)}, 
        line width=.05pt, 
        %x=5mm, 
        %scale=1.\xi,
        yshift=\xi*12
        ]
    \draw[black,bottom color=#2, top color=#2] (-\mwid,0) -- (-\mwid+.4,-1) arc (190:350:\marc cm and 5mm) -- (\mwid,0);
    \draw[black,fill=#3] (0,0) ellipse (\mwid cm and 5mm);
    \path (-\mwid,0) -- (-\mwid+.4,-1) coordinate[midway] (a\xi);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
latent/.style={%
        ,circle
        ,draw
        ,thick
        ,minimum size=10mm
        }


\foreach \text
        [%
        count=\xi starting from 0, 
        evaluate=\xi as \shadecolor using int(25*\xi),
        evaluate=\xi as \coord using int(\xi-12)
        ] 
    in {%
        Discuss and conclude\\overall findings,
        Combine the data\\\tiny\itshape (synthesis or meta-analysis),
        Assess the quality\\of the studies,
        Extract data from the studies
    }{%
        \funnel{\coord}{mgreen!\shadecolor !myellow}{mgreen!\shadecolor !myellow}
        \node[align=right, anchor=east, inner sep=10pt, font=\scriptsize, text width=2cm] at (a\xi) {\text};
    }   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I am looking for two things:

A set of an arbitrary number of ever-larger cylinders on top of each other with texts on the side, starting from the top.
Following the ever-larger cylinders, a set of an arbitrary number of ever-smaller cylinders on top of each other with texts on the side, starting from the top. (Effectively the same as the example, but rather than starting from the bottom and go up, it would start from the top and go down.)

Ideally the size of the last (and the widest) cylinder from 1 would transition smoothly to the top-most cylinder from 2.
In other words, I would like to have to have a set of cylinders first expanding as we move down and then narrowing.
Thus far I have been tinkering with the funnel function by trying various combinations of positive and negative signs for \xi, \mwid, etc. None of the combinations have worked. Embarrassingly while the example code produces a wonder set of cylinders almost what I wanted, the PGF/TikZ code in it is much too advanced for my understanding.
**Edits: 1. adding the final sentence as it was cut off; 2. steps I have attempted at creating what I wanted.

Have you made an attempt other than copying the indicated code?  Could you finish up your post?  It ends a bit abruptly.

Thank you, @Teepeemm. Somehow the end of my post was cut off. I have added the sentence that was missing. I also added what I have done at your suggestion.
